# Flexbox header: Align box right with two elements in rows

Tags: css, flexbox

Just starting out with Flexbox. Practicing by trying to create a very simple CV website.

Codepen is here:
http://codepen.io/koentj/pen/jyLxGX

I'm trying to get the `social-container` to the left of the `picture-container`. Both of these are within the `profile-container`, while giving `name-container` most of the space (aka `profile-container` will use what it needs, and `name-container` takes the rest).

Whatever I do (and I've tried a bunch), the `social-container` ends up above the `picture-container` and I feel like I'm missing something extremely rudimentary.

Comment: You should first clean up your HTML, `<main>` isn't closed correctly and you are missing some closing `</div>`s

Comment: Sorry about that! Should be fixed now. Thanks for the heads-up. I kind of got lost in a tangle when adding new `<div>`s, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if your HTML is reflecting what you are trying to do. Currently it's like this:

```
- header
-- .name-container  
-- .profile-container
--- .social-container
---- .picture-container
```

It would be easier if `.picture-container` would be a sibling of `.social-container` rather than a child element.

That way you could use `display: flex` for `.profile-container` and would get the two elements side by side.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Liberation Sans, Arial, sans-serif";
}

header {
  background: #42A8C0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.profile-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <div class="name-container">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
    <h4>Small summary of current position</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="profile-container">
    <div class="social-container">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="picture-container">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/22/18/57/puppy-1216269_960_720.jpg" class="portrait-pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to accomplish. Somewhere along the line I got my parent-child relationships confused. With some added padding it now looks like I want it to!